# Ayuda con eclipse c++

Tags: c++

cuando compilo el hello world de ejemplo que trae eclipse me compila bien

pero si lo creo desde cero en otro proyecto  me este error

```
   11:42:22 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project hello 2 ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\hello 2.o" "..\\src\\hello 2.cpp" 
g++ -o "hello 2.exe" "src\\hello 2.o" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

11:42:23 Build Finished (took 422ms)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hay un espacio en el nombre del archivo, "hello 2.c", te recomiendo que lo elimines. no es una buena idea usar espacios en los nombres de archivo pues no todos los sistemas operativos los interpretan de la misma manera.

Comment: @erik asegura crear tu proyecto como "console program", revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Me llamo la atención tu problema ya que el mensaje de error :

> undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Generalmente se refiere a que no se tiene un "Entry Point", en pocas palabras un `main()` definido.

Pero por lo que veo estas iniciando en C++ ya que creaste un "Hello world", **asegura crear tu proyecto como "console program", probablemente lo estas creando como "Windows program"**.

Answer (score 0):

Evidentemente el error no es de código, si no del archivo en donde se está guardando el archivo, procura no guardar con espacios los nombres de archivos y si necesitas distinguir entre dos palabras es de buenas prácticas, escribir `nombre1Nombre2`, o `nombre1_nombre2`.